# how to handle file whose size is more than 2 GB?

Tags: c

in c fseek,fopen this all function works for long int means only handle file of 2 gb.
now how can i open file whose size is more than 2 GB?

Comment: This is a platform specific issue, not a "C" issue.

Comment: you mean if i have 64 bit platform than i can ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091304/handling-files-greater-than-2-gb-in-msvc6 or http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Opening-Streams.html#index-fopen64-931

Comment: @Mr.32: That depends. How does that 64-bit platform implement fseek?

Comment: Change your nickname to Mr.64.

Comment: fopen doesn't depend on the size of long. If you don't need to fseek, but just read the file sequentially you should be fine. Also, on **some** 64-bit systems `long` is 64 bit.

Comment: What platform are you in ? On linux there are 64 bit versions of IO functions: `fopen64`, `fseek64`, etc

Comment: @Alexandre C. ya i m working on 32 bit linux

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035657/seeking-and-reading-large-files-in-a-linux-c-application . Closing as duplicate

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As the commenters have already explained, whether you can open a file of more than 2GB depends on the OS and C library, not on the compiler on `sizeof(long)`. If your OS supports such files, you should be able to `fopen` them, although you may have to set a flag (`#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64` for Linux).

Then, `fseek` indeed cannot seek to positions farther away than `LONG_MAX` in a single call. You can either call `fseek` several times in a loop, which can be cumbersome, or check if your platform has `fseeko` which takes an offset argument of type `off_t`. That type should be big enough to capture the size of any (regular) file on your system if you set the right options. `fseeko` is available on newer Linux and all POSIX-2001-compliant OSs.

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain? I'd like to know if I've made a mistake.

Comment: On 32-bit Linux Ubuntu 13.x here. Having this issue with fopen, without  fseek. `#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64` is needed to get the program to even open large files. So, no, it is not always OS limitations but sometimes just hard-coded garbage in C libs.

Comment: @AndrewJohnson That doesn't contradict my answer: you need at least OS support for this to work, and `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS` is in the answer.

Comment: It directly contradicts your first paragraph. My OS supports such files, but I am not able to just `fopen` them. The preprocessor directive is needed for C to compile with large file support.

Comment: @AndrewJohnson: ok. Made the answer more precise, please check.